# Maven Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.1

Tags: maven, maven-2

My software version:

- Eclipse for Java Developers: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2
- SVN Plugin: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

The exception message:

> `Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: **Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)**: The operation was cancelled. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources:default-resources:process-resources)`

But the junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 can be found through the following link:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20v%3A%223.8.1%22

There isn't any HTTP proxy.

How can I resolve the problem? Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Did you try forcing an update with `-U`, as the message indicates?

Comment: A more extreme way to force an update is to delete the local repository under "$HOME/.m2/repository"

Comment: The logs indicate `The operation was cancelled` - network issues maybe?

Comment: **was cached in the local repository** . You have to delete at least $M2_HOME/repository/junit/junit directory

Comment: Reply Raghuram&khmarbaise: what kind of network issue it is?

Comment: Reply to Mark O'Connor: Your solution works! Thanks!