# Unable to build Maven project due to some dependency issues

Tags: rest, maven

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6
>       from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>       resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed
>       or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>       org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central
>       (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

This is the error I am getting in my *pom.xml*. I don't know what is that. I am pasting my *pom.xml*:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.sanket</groupId>
<artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>messenger</name>

<build>
    <finalName>messenger</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency> -->


</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

When I remove comment to add moxy jar dependency for JSON, it gives few more errors. Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: See [Maven Could not transfer artifact ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788225/maven-could-not-transfer-artifact-junitjunitjar3-8-1).

Comment: thanx. I got the solution from above link.